# AngularJS: How to change data in ng-repeat upon model change in service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service, controller

I try to update the info shown in a "ng-repeat"-div when the connected variable changes in a service. According to this [fiddle by Ian Brown](http://jsfiddle.net/zymotik/853wvv7s/) the data in the HTML code should be updated every time when the BikeService.bikes variable is changed. When I open the website in my browser (Browser A), then adding bikes works perfectly (locally and remotely). Now I open the page with another browser (Browser B) on either my own machine or another machine. Also in that browser everything works perfectly, when bikes are added from THAT browser. Here my code:

### HTML

```
<div ng-app"ubobApp">
  <!--For testing purposes I added 2 buttons each adding a new bike.
  One does so "locally", i.e. within the browser, and the other does
  it "remotely" by communicating with a MongoDB-controller using a web socket-->
  <div ng-controller="buttonCtrl">
    <md-button class="primary" ng-click="localAddRandomBike()">
        Local: Add Random Bike
    </md-button>
    <md-button class="primary" ng-click="remoteAddRandomBike()">
        Remote: Add Random Bike
    </md-button>
  </div>

  <!--Here the data is displayed using the GoogleMaps API-->
  <md-content flex ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ng-map center="[53.219, 6.567]" zoom="13" id="map">
      <marker ng-repeat="bike in service.bikes"
        icon={{image}}
        title="Title"
        position="{{bike.lon}}, {{bike.lat}}"
        z-index="1"
      ></marker>
    </ng-map>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var ubob = angular.module('ubobApp', ['ngMap']);

ubob.service('BikeService', function() {
  this.bikes = [
    new Bike(53.224, 6.558, true)
  ];

  this.addBike = function(bike) {
    this.bikes.push(bike);
  };
}

ubob.service('WebsocketService', function (BikeService) {
  var socket = new WebSocket(...url...);
  socket.onmessage = onMessage;

  this.onMessage = function(event) {
    var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    switch (message.action) {
      case "addBike":
        var bike = new Bike(message.lon, message.lat, message.available);
        BikeService.addBike(bike);
        break;
      ...Some other cases...
    }
  }

  this.addRandomBike = function (bike) {
    var data = {
      action: "addBike",
      lon: bike.lon,
      lat: bike.lat,
      available: bike.available
    };

    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});

ubob.controller('buttonCtrl', function ($scope, BikeService, WebsocketService) {
  $scope.localAddRandomBike = function() {
    var lon = getRandomArbitrary(53.15, 53.25);
    var lat = getRandomArbitrary(6.55, 6.57);
    BikeService.addBike(new Bike(lon, lat, true));
  };

  $scope.remoteAddRandomBike = function () {
    var lon = getRandomArbitrary(53.15, 53.25);
    var lat = getRandomArbitrary(6.54, 6.58);
    WebsocketService.addRandomBike(new Bike(lon, lat, true))
  }
});

ubob.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, BikeService) {
  $scope.image = {url: 'img/bike64.png', ...otherConfig...};
  $scope.service = BikeService;
});
```

Now comes the weird part; Bikes should also be displayed in Browser A when they are added in Browser B. That does not happen. Browser A receives the object and also adds it to the BikeService.bikes-array, but it does not display it. I have then to click on either one of the "Add Bike" buttons and then the bike created in Browser B is shown together with the bike which was just created in Browser A.
I have the slight suspicion that it has something to do with asynchronous modification of the BikeService.bikes variable, but I'm not sure. Any other suggestions, please? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the wrong use of `this`

```
    ubob.service('BikeService', function() {
      var self = this;

      self.bikes = [
        new Bike(53.224, 6.558, true)
      ];

      self.addBike = function(bike) {
        self.bikes.push(bike);
      };
     }
```

Comment: ThAnk you for your answer. However I also tried writing it without "self" but with "this" instead. Still didn't work. But I'll give it another shot later.

Comment: Sorry I thought you copied my code there. Tried both versions, one with this and the other with the code you provided. Both had the same problem. But I'll check it again.